# How to refresh view when vuex store changes?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I get the data from the store like so

```
  computed: {
    notes() {
      var data = this.$store.getters.getNotes;
      var key = this.$store.getters.getTitleFilter;
      if (key === "all") return data;
      return data.filter((note) => {
        var filteredNote = note.category.some(({ name }) => name === key);
        if (filteredNote) return filteredNote;
      });
    },
  },
```

When the note array changes (an item is removed, `getNotes` should reflect that. In other instances (where the `data` is returned without filtering) this used to do the trick:

```
  watch: {
    notes(newval) {
      return newval;
    },
  },
```

I there a way to get the filtered array to update?

Comment: Is [mapGetters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper) what do you need?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle of your issue?